# EntityManager.save() returns null values for unprovided fields

Tags: typescript, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I'm working with `@nestjs/typeorm": "^8.0.2`, with Postgres
I'm having the following issue, that seems like a very strange behavior:

When saving a partial entity, the fields I send are saved correctly, but the **returned value** includes more fields, with null values.
So I can't rely on the returned object because it includes wrong values now.

For example (very much simplified of course), I have a Project Entity:

```
class Project extends BaseEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @Column({ length: 150 })
    name: string;

    @Column({ nullable: true })
    data?: string;
}
```

And I want to update only the name, so let's say I have this function:

```
async saveName(proj: {id: number, name: string}): Promise<Partial<IProject>> {
    ... [some code]...
   return await entityManager.save(Project,  proj);
}
```

Now, assuming I have in the DB:

```
{id: 1, name: 'a', data: 'my data' }
```

and I call:

```
await saveName({id: 1, name: 'b'})
```

the returned value will be:

```
{id: 1, name: 'b', data: NULL }
```

I would expect the returned value to be:

```
{id: 1, name: 'b'}
```

or:
`{id: 1, name: 'b', data: 'my data' }` (less good, but at least it would be correct)

Please assume:

1. This scenario is essential for my type of project.
2. I can't always predict the list of fields to update, I need to update the received object.

Bottom line, **the returned value is incorrect**.
Isn't it a bug?
Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

`EntityManager.save()` method returns partial model instance with keys you updated plus defaults provided by the database (in your case it's `null`, because `data` column is set to be nullable). Unfortunately this behaviour is not documented well enough.

What you can do is:

- [Add `reload: true` to options of `save` method](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3490#issuecomment-585728706)
- Query for whole model again, for example using Query Builder.

Comment: Thanks, it really seems like an odd behavior. Why would a nullable field be returned with null value? It should not be returned, or at least be returned with its actual value. Anyway, the reload doesn't work on this database, so I do have to query the whole model again. Not a nice solution...

Comment: I believe it's connected to optimisation of `save` queries, to not query whole model every time you saved something. Also, using Query Builder also for saving data into database gives you more control about your queries, but it has  drawback of being more procedural and less declarative.